# How to remove child where text = "text"

Tags: javascript

I tried to delete element's child that has innerHTML or another attribute equal to some value. How can i implement something like LINQ in C#.

```
element.removeChild(element.nodeChilds.Where(child => child.innerHTML = "Hello"));
```

Comment: What HTML are you working with, and where did you get stuck? Did you make an attempt? How did it not work, what errors were generated, what did it do wrong? What do you want to work with, attributes, or properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/find) to find element with specified `innerHTML` attribute and remove it.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('parent');
    elem.removeChild(Array.from(elem.childNodes).find(v => v.innerHTML == 'text'));
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <p>empty</p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That will only remove the first instance of a matching node; and in order to teach the OP, and future users, please take the time to explain your code.

Comment: @DavidThomas *I tried to delete element's child that has innerHTML* - OP specified his desired result - **child**, not children.

Comment: Fair enough; but given the vagaries and ambiguity of the rest of the question I don't believe the OP *meant* only ever a single child. But it remains your answer, obviously.

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what i looked for.

Comment: @DavidThomas, as for to find all children i can just use Array.filter() which is same to Array.find(), but result is array

Answer (score 1):

The following will remove all children that match your criteria:

```
var children = element.children, len = children.length, i;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (children[i] && children[i].innerHTML === "Hello") {
        element.removeChild(children[i]);
        i--;
    }
}
```